# How to Create Rounded Bar Charts vega

Tags: vega, vega-lite

I am using vega library to render my column chart, I have gone through all the provided example in vega site but unable to find how I can make rounded column of my column chart,

Thank you very much if anybody can help
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `cornerRadius` property of the mark.

```
"mark": {
  "type": "rect",
  "cornerRadius": 10
},
```

[image]

Try it here: https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6ALQAbZskoAmOgCtY3AHaQANOCgATZAgBOjQnh4qckAIJhYjVITHIw7dLrBIneMAHdmiMGnbJNbU0wTXQ8ejUNSFDw7DBQCAhICnQxVh04gG0NRPjITFMzNUh2OOkADgBfVTyCqAAhYtKcAFYW6tq4yABhJriAFgBmapzE4HyugBE+nABOAEYO8brIAFEZsHLFmuWugDENluH1XIhd0wBxDfnZpYnTAAkN8oB2O5WASUPpStGAXQ0I0gGF0AGs4gkoHgAJ6EZBdXTIeB4SJJeDcXRKZC6ABK6E0jFYsDi8wADCARklkEp0QSlNQIaNIAAPCGQABmjGQYk0XUwNUgMLhXQxdNSkEpiUg0LZnO5vNMpQFQvhpgAjqx0EojOEjFQJYCKSAgA